# Visual Studio Code codelens doesn't work on variables

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, codelens

I'm developing an game with c# unity and I'm using Visual Studio Code as IDE. However the codelens doesn't work on variables - only properties, classes.. etc at some point as shown in the screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jB4GD.png)

I'd appreciate it if you can help me. thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7HMw.png)

I found C# codelens settings but it must work correctly in the present state.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: is what's shown in your screenshot really variables? Aren't those class fields?

Answer (score 3):

The new extension C#(2.x.x) of Visual Studio Code did have a problem.
What I tried to fix the problem.

Solution: Downgrade the version of the C# extension to 1.26.0.

- Step 1: Open Visual Studio Code, click on Extention icon.
- Step 2: Search C#, probably the current version is 2.x.x.
- Step 3: Click on the arrow next to uninstall, select install another version.
- Step 4: Select 1.26.0.

Note: if it requires remove extensions to reinstall C#, just remove all other extensions.
Now my references of variables are back.

[Downgrade picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRDRg.png)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed.
The problem was occurred because c# extension setting reset and omnisharp setting was not loaded after visual code updated.

Comment: so what did you do to fix the issue?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).